# A form that changes email and password

Tags: python, django

I want to write a form that will display the user's email but allow them to change their password by entering their current password and their new password twice. I want to use a `ModelForm`, too.

I have the `User`:

```
# models.py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

And I've started on a form:

```
# forms.py
class ChangeAccountDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    current_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

I've created a simple view that only works with a GET request at the minute:

```
# views.py
def edit_account_details(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        account_form = ChangeAccountDetailsForm()
        return render(request, 'freelancestudent/edit_account_details.html', {
            {'form': account_form}
        })
    else:
        pass
```

And a simple HTML file that simply calls `{{form.as_p}}`. When I run it as is I get the error `unhashable type: 'dict'` at `{'form': account_form}`. How can I display, then, the current user's email and allow functionality for changing password. Is this possible with a ModelForm or will I have to roll my own form and do all the logic myself?

Comment: Note that your problem is not at all related to what the form does; but also note that Django's auth framework includes [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) and [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms) that do exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
return render(
   request, 
  'freelancestudent/edit_account_details.html', {
            {'form': account_form}
        })
```

You have two sets of `{}`. The inner one defines a `dict`, the outer one defines a `set`, so it's equivalent to:

```
context = {'form': account_form}
whatever = set(context)
```

Now `sets` needs their values to be hashable (just like `dict` keys), and a `dict` is not hashable, hence your error message.

But anyway: `render` expects a `dict`, not a `set`, so what you want is:

```
return render(
   request, 
  'freelancestudent/edit_account_details.html', 
  {'form': account_form}
  )
```